# can we can confess our love in islam

Tags: halal-haram, love

assalamualaikum
i am sorry if there is any mistake i am a new user please kindly help me out
i am in trouble condition **a muslim guy had proposed me days earlier he is a hafiz and a relegious person ,i too have feeling for him is it permissable in islam for me to confess my love towards him and tell him to avoid all the haram activities like looking each other,smiling ,dating or even talking each other .
recently i came to hear boyfriend -girlfriend relation is prohbited in islam but we both are only 16 we cant get marry at this age due to law (in our country marriage is possible only after 21yrs ) *so is it allowed for me to confess my love and wait till the age without being into boyfriend girlfriend relation***

please help me out i am totally confused .
looking forward for an early answer please  ..thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wa Alaykum s-salam, For the better side not to confess your love and wait till the age without being into boyfriend girlfriend relation. And tell him relations before marriage is haram to save him from further mistakes.

Comment: thank you for your answer ,i am worried if i do not confess it sometimes he may look out for another girl .

Comment: Then I think that's best for you or for him. If it's love then I think he'll wait else it is an attraction for short time not love.

Comment: brother do i need to tell it is haram or simply tell i am not interested because there are so many muslim couples are there in my class if i say to him so he will tell his friends and it will end our friendship

Comment: confessing love is not haram if you are able/ready to marriage to him. But in your scenario, you are underage, and confessing now means involve in a relationship without marriage which is haram.